# Avoid dragging down formulas while copying formula to a range (without using "$" sign)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy, range

In the following code I'm trying to copy a reference to a cell as formula into a Range.
I want to propagate this formula reference to the entire Range but when I do that the following way:
`.Range("D" & firstRow & ":D" & secondRow).formula = "=D" & Middle`
The variable "Middle" increments.

So I've tried to use `.Range("D" & firstRow & ":D" & secondRow).formula = "=D" & Middle` and instead of having the following outcome:

```
row     D
105   =D107
106   =D107
107   =D107
108   =D107
109   =D107
```

I get the following:

```
row     D
105   =D107
106   =D108
107   =D109
108   =D110
109   =D111
```

Please keep in mind, I'm aware that if instead of writting formula as `"=D" & Middle` I could write `"=D$" & Middle` and the problem will disappear. However I do not want to use the dollar sign, as the final range will later be copied to another range down below, and the references should change accordingly.

Here's my code:

```
    Middle, ManagAreaLength, secondRow, firstRow As Long
    Middle = 107
    firstRow = 105
    secondRow= 109
    ManagAreaLength = secondRow - firstRow + 1

    Dim TmpArray() As Variant
    ReDim TmpArray(ManagAreaLength)
    
    For i = LBound(TmpArray) To UBound(TmpArray)
        TmpArray(i) = "=D" & Middle
    Next i  

    Worksheets("Model").Range("D" & firstRow & ":D" & secondRow).formula = TmpArray()
```

Comment: First, this won't work. You cannot write into D107 the formula `=D107` because this is a circular reference. Second the array needs to be a 2 dimensional array TmpArray(rows, columns) even if it has only one column. • Can you please explain what you try to do and how to get around the first issue? I can then help with the second one.

Comment: Apart from what @Peh mentions you could place the formula as absolute rows and then use `Application.ConvertFormula(<formula reference>, xlA1, xlA1, 4)`  to convert them to relative.  [ConvertFormula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.convertformula)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook but that does not work with ranges nor with arrays because the first parameter of `.ConvertFormula` requires: *"A string that contains the formula that you want to convert. This must be a valid formula, and it must begin with an equal sign."* • And if you have to loop through the cells anyway this is the slowest solution possible.

Comment: @Peh, I do agree with the two dimensional array way of doing it.  But.... adding the `$` to `TmpArray(i) = "=D" & Middle`, using `Worksheets("Model").Range("D" & firstRow & ":D" & secondRow)` as a `With` statement and then `.Formula = TmpArray()` and `.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, 4)` within the `With... End With` block worked.  No loops needed - except he `TmpArray` one.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the existence of "ConvertFormula" solution!

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Well, then the documentation is weird. This solution would be the easiest then as it does not require an array at all. Added this to my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine this data

[image]

And this code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FillFormulaUsingArray()
    Dim Middle As Long
    Middle = 5
    
    Dim firstRow As Long
    firstRow = 1
    
    Dim secondRow As Long
    secondRow = 10
    
    Dim ManagAreaLength As Long
    ManagAreaLength = secondRow - firstRow + 1

    Dim TmpArray() As Variant
    ReDim TmpArray(1 To ManagAreaLength, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(TmpArray, 1) To UBound(TmpArray, 1)
        TmpArray(i, 1) = "=A" & Middle
    Next i

    Worksheets("Model").Range("B" & firstRow & ":B" & secondRow).Formula = TmpArray()
End Sub
```

And it will produce

[image]

Where all cells in B are `=A5`.

What you need to be careful with is if you write arrays to cells (doesn't matter if values or formulas) you need 2 dimensional arrays that start counting with `1` **even if theres only one column you need to define that: For example `Dim Arr(1 To 10, 1 To 1)` is an array of 10 rows and 1 column (you cannot omit the column part!).

And then writing this array to the cells will write exactly the content of that array.

If you do `.formula = TmpArray()` with a 1 dimensional array (as you have in your code in the question) this will only write the first value of the array into the cells and not the entire array because the array dimensions do not fit the dimensions of the cells. And therefore the formula gets adjusted to the other cells.

Note that you still have the issue that you cannot write the formula `=D107` into `D107` because the cell would reference to itself which is a circular reference.

Just one more note: If you declare `Dim Middle, ManagAreaLength, secondRow, firstRow As Long` then only the last variable is of type `Long` all the others are of type `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable or it is `Variant` by default: `Dim Middle As Long, ManagAreaLength As Long, secondRow As Long, firstRow As Long`.

Good practice is to declare a variable as close as possible to its first use and avoid `Variant` where ever possible.

---

### Solution without array using `Application.ConvertFormula`

```
Public Sub FillFormulaConvert()
    Dim Middle As Long
    Middle = 5
    
    Dim firstRow As Long
    firstRow = 1
    
    Dim secondRow As Long
    secondRow = 10
    
    Dim ManagAreaLength As Long
    ManagAreaLength = secondRow - firstRow + 1

    With Worksheets("Model").Range("B" & firstRow & ":B" & secondRow)
        .Formula = "=A$" & Middle
        .Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, 4)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Thank you for your advices! The middle value will be replaced just after this operation. Firstly, I'll set the cells to point onto the middle cell, and right after that, the middle cell will receive a specific formula

Answer (score 1):

### Write Formula

- Using an array is the superior solution since you are writing to the worksheet only once. The issues you are having with it are correctly covered in Pᴇʜ's answer.
- Since there are just a few cells, you could do the one thing you didn't want to do, and in the 2nd go, replace the dollar sign (`$`) with an empty string.

```vb
Sub WriteFormula()
    
    Const WS_NAME As string = "Model"
    Const SRC_COLUMN As String = "D"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "E"
    Const FIRST As Long = 105
    Const MIDDLE As Long = 107
    Const LAST As Long = 109

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = ws.Range(SRC_COLUMN & FIRST & ":" & SRC_COLUMN & LAST)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN)
    
    drg.Formula = "=" & SRC_COLUMN & "$" & MIDDLE
    drg.Replace "$", "", xlPart

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This was just a small code snipped, this operation will be done in multiple places on the sheet and multiple times, so I needed something that will be quick enough and in lesser code lines